# C++ Does typeid return string type?

Tags: c++

When we use typeid i.e typeid(variable).name() 
Does it give out string as the output because if it does it could be helpful in comparisons with strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard, it is an implementation-defined null-terminated `const char*`:

> **18.7.1 Class type_info**
>   ....
>
> `const char* name() const noexcept;`
>
> *Returns*: An implementation-defined `NTBS`.
>
> *Remarks*: The message may be a null-terminated multibyte string (17.5.2.1.4.2), suitable for conversion
>   and display as a `wstring` (21.3, 22.4.1.4)

Since the content is implementation-defined, it cannot be compared with other strings in a reliable way, unless we restrict ourselves to specific implementations.

Answer (score 3):

`typeid(variable).name()` [returns](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/typeinfo) a pointer a null terminated string, which can be compared using `strcmp()`. However a better way to check a type of variable is

```
 if (typeid(a) == typeid(int))
```

Comment: Even for a User defined data type, we can use this right? typeid(a) == typeid(class) where a is an object of class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting Ss when I try this.

```
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string str = "string";
    cout << typeid(str).name();
    return 0;
}
```

Try it: http://cpp.sh/4lsw

Comment: Interesting... But it doesn't seem relevant. Thanks anyway though, that's a good puzzler why it's giving Ss... 